# Не работает pipreqs Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

Установил `pipreqs` для `python3`, но пишет что команда не найдена
[image]

Но я могу импортировать библиотеку из python:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работаю в Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Т.к. у вас пакеты ставятся в `~/.local`, скорее всего и исполняемый файл находится в `~/.local/bin`. Попробуйте вызвать `./.local/bin/pipreqs`. Если сработает, то стоит добавить этот путь в переменную окружения `PATH`.

Comment: `python<version> -m pipreqs` ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ```/usr/bin/python3: No module named pipreqs.__main__; 'pipreqs' is a package and cannot be directly executed```

Comment: @mkkik Ваш способ сработал, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По выводу `pip3 install` видно, что пакеты устанавливаются в `user`-директорию `~/.local/lib/...`, что говорит о значении параметра установки `--prefix=$HOME/.local`. Соответственно, исполняемый файл, идущий в составе пакета, будет нахоиться по пути `$HOME/.local/bin`

Тогда, для запуска надо указать полный путь:

```
~/.local/bin/pipreqs
```

Чтобы не писать полный путь каждый раз, а также, чтобы были видны другие скрипты из этой директории, необходимо добавить путь в переменную окружения `$PATH`. В файле `.bashrc` (или в соответсвующем файле конфигурации для других командных оболочек) необходимо добавить строку:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```